# TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

Tags: python

```
from file import x
a = x
if i in a:
    dosomething
```

file.py:

```
class x:
def __init__(self):
    self.q = []

def __contains__(self,item):
    return item in self.q

def __iter__(self):
    for i in self.q:
        yield i
```

Get error: TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

How i can fix this?

Comment: You want an instance of `x`: `a = x()`. In your current code `a` is just an other name for the class `x`.

Comment: `for variable in something` is an iteration. If `something` is not a collection that can be iterated over, you will see this error. In your case, you are trying to iterate over a `type`, which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. a=x() worked!